# Kotlin generic Out-projected type prohibits the use of

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I'm using kind of dynamic form system coming from the backend. To be able to map my form I have a visitor pattern with generics, I have it working in Java but I can't make it to work in Kotlin.

I have this interface:

```
internal interface FormFieldAccessor<T> {

    fun getFormField(formFieldDefinition: FormFieldDefinition): FormField<T>

    fun setValueToBuilder(builder: Builder, value: T)

    fun accept(visitor: FormFieldVisitor)

    fun getValue(personalInfo: PersonalInfo): T
}
```

Then I have my list of accessors like this:

```
val accessors = mutableMapOf<String, FormFieldAccessor<*>>()
accessors[FIRST_NAME] = object : FormFieldAccessor<String> {
            override fun getValue(personalInfo: PersonalInfo): String {
                return personalInfo.surname
            }

            override fun accept(visitor: FormFieldVisitor) {
                visitor.visitString(this)
            }

            override fun getFormField(formFieldDefinition: FormFieldDefinition): FormField<String> {
                //not relevant
            }

            override fun setValueToBuilder(builder: Builder, value: String) {
                builder.withSurname(value)
            }
        }
//more other accessors with different type like Int or Boolean
```

And want to use it like this:

```
accessors[FIRST_NAME]!!.setValueToBuilder(builder, field.value )
```

But this is not working and give me:

```
Out-projected type 'FormFieldAccessor<*>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun setValueToBuilder(builder: Builder, value: T): Unit defined in FormFieldAccessor'
```

If you have an idea of what I'm doing wrong would be cool :)

EDIT: here is a smaller gist of the structure I have https://gist.github.com/jaumard/1fd1ccc9db0374cb5d08f047414a6bc8

I don't want to loose the type by using Any, feel frustrated compare to Java as it's really easy to implement. I understand the problem with the star projection now but is there anything else than this to achieve the same as in java ?

Answer (score 1):

Using [star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) indicates that you know nothing about the actual type, as the documentation tells:

> Sometimes you want to say that you know nothing about the type argument, but still want to use it in a safe way. The safe way here is to define such a projection of the generic type, that every concrete instantiation of that generic type would be a subtype of that projection.
>
> [...]
>
> For `Foo<out T : TUpper>`, where `T` is a covariant type parameter with the upper bound `TUpper`, `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<out TUpper>`. It means that when the `T` is **unknown** you can *safely read* values of `TUpper` from `Foo<*>`.

What you can do is casting to the appropriate type:

```
(accessors[FIRST_NAME] as FormFieldAccessor<String>).setValueToBuilder(builder, field.value)
```

Yet, these types of casts are error-prone and a safer way would be the following;

```
object FormFieldProvider {
    private val accessors = mutableMapOf<String, FormFieldAccessor<*>>()
    fun <T : Any> addAccessor(key: String, fieldValidator: FormFieldAccessor<T>) {
        accessors[key] = fieldValidator
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    operator fun <T : Any> get(key: String): FormFieldAccessor<T> =
            accessors[key] as? FormFieldAccessor<T>
                    ?: throw IllegalArgumentException(
                            "No accessor found for $key")
}
```

The access to the star-projected map got wrapped in an object and accessing the values is safe with this solution.

You can use it like this:

```
FormFieldProvider.addAccessor(FIRST_NAME, object : FormFieldAccessor<String> {
    //...
})

FormFieldProvider.get<String>(FIRST_NAME).setValueToBuilder(...)
```

Comment: I tried to test some your solution but wasn't able to make it compile either, it's part of some legacy system written in Java and I need to keep the same structure in Kotlin :( I update the issue with a simple gist file to show you the structure I have if you don't mind give it a try

Answer (score 0):

@s1m0nw1's answer gives you the reason for the problem and the simple fix. However, with your setup there may also be another possibility.

Add

```
fun setValueFromForm(builder: Builder, fieldDefinition: FormFieldDefinition) { 
    setValueToBuilder(builder, getFormField(fieldDefinition).value)
}
```

to `FormFieldAccessor<T>`. Because its signature doesn't involve `T`, it can be safely called on a `FormFieldAccessor<*>`.

And if you also store `FormFieldDefinition`s in a map, you can now call it

```
accessors[FIRST_NAME]!!.setValueToBuilder(builder, fieldDefinitions[FIRST_NAME]!!)
```

Further improvements would depend on details of your system.

EDIT:

I'm reasonably certain even without seeing the Java code that it uses raw types (i.e. `FormFieldAccessor` instead of `FormFieldAccessor<Something>` or `FormFieldAccessor<?>`). Something like

```
Map<String, FormFieldAccessor> accessors = new HashMap<>();
...
accessors.get(FIRST_NAME).setValueToBuilder(builder, field.value);
```

But this is also unsafe, the compiler just ignores the problems instead of telling you about them. The value of `accessors.get(FIRST_NAME)` can still actually be e.g. an `FormFieldAccessor<Boolean>`, in which case `setValueToBuilder` will fail with a `ClassCastException`. You can see this by accidentally passing the wrong name to `get` or storing the wrong accessor in the map: it won't stop anything from compiling.

Instead, better Java code would use `Map<String, FormFieldAccessor<?>>` and then require a cast after `get` just as Kotlin code does.

Raw types exist primarily to allow very old pre-Java-5 code to still compile. Kotlin doesn't have this consideration, so it doesn't support raw types and your only option there is to do what you *should* do in Java.

Comment: I also tried to test your solution but wasn't able to make it compile either, it's part of some legacy system written in Java and I need to keep the same structure in Kotlin :( I update the issue with a simple gist file to show you the structure I have if you don't mind give it a try

Comment: I don't store the formFieldDefinition as I'm already under a loop a fieldDefinition at the time I want to setValueToBuilder :(

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain why your Java code is likely simply hiding the problems.

Comment: "as I'm already under a loop a fieldDefinition at the time I want to setValueToBuilder" That's actually better, it means it's already available and doesn't need to be stored.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, you're right it use the old raw type... I say fieldDefinition but it's formField, I didn't have the formDefinition at that point unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can add a wrapper method that takes Any as a value and checks its type

```
internal interface FormFieldAccessor<T> {


    fun getFormField(formFieldDefinition: FormFieldDefinition): FormField<T>

    fun _setValueToBuilder(builder: Builder, value: T)

    fun setValueToBuilder(builder: Builder, value: Any){
        val value  = value as? T ?: return
        _setValueToBuilder(builder, value)
    }

    fun accept(visitor: FormFieldVisitor)

    fun getValue(personalInfo: PersonalInfo): T
}
```